# How can I edit the bones in an armature without affecting the mesh parented to it?

Tags: armature, bones

I have figure that is made out of a set of separate objects, kind of like a marionette. I want to animate it with one, unified armature. I already parented my armature to the figure and made some testing animations. During this period I found out that the joints of the armature are not quite where they need to be for optimal posing. My problem is when I edit the armature in edit mode, the tweaked bones take the parented objects with them, deforming my figure.

To demonstrate this I have a small self contained example:

First I have my figure made of separate objects.

[image]

Then I create bones for them, separately, to eliminate the need to weight 
paint later.

[image]

I parent the bones to the objects with the bone option.

[image]

Then I join the bones.

And then, when I proceed to parent the bones to each other, the first problem arises: the meshes deform with the bones, even though I did the parenting in edit mode.

[image]

Then finally, when I tweak the bones, again, in edit mode, the meshes deform further.

[image]

I also have the [.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7yujw2vbpqjoh0/armature_test.blend?dl=0) file of the example.

Comment: could it be just needed to adjust/reset weights?

Comment: Thanks, the weight tip gave me a clue. I devised a workaround. I no longer parent with the bone option, rather with empty groups and put the corresponding vertices into each bone's vertex group.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, however I have far more bones and objects so weight-painting them all individually is a solution I would hope to avoid.